# What is the most readable way to replace multiple strings with replacements in a string in postgresql.

Tags: postgresql, replace

My usecase is something like this :

```
String = "INDIA CANADA ITALY",
String Post Repacement = "IN CA IT"
```

I'm looking for something like this :

```
replaceMultiple(String, "INDIA", "IN", "CANADA", "CA", "ITALY", "IT")
```

I'm currently doing this by using nested replace, but it's not readable much, and if I want to add more replacements, I'll have nest it further more.

Can this be achieved by functions, like creating a temporary table in runtime with key-value pairs, and replace every key in string with value. 
Or some other method?

Comment: Are you looking for regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ])?

Comment: @ChrisB AFAIK regexp_replace(source, pattern, replacement [, flags ]) only works for a pattern to be substituted with a single replacement. What I am looking for is multiple key-value replacements.

Comment: If readability is a concern, I would write my own function `replace_multiple()`

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it.

You could use temporary tables and `regexp_replace`, or you could use a JSON dictionary like this:

```
SELECT string_agg(
          COALESCE(
             '{ "INDIA": "IN", "CANADA": "CA", "ITALY": "IT" }'::jsonb->>s,
             s
          ),
          ' '
       )
FROM regexp_split_to_table('INDIA CANADA ITALY', '\s') s;
```